# Do microkernels also have per process stack like Linux has?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, microkernel

I came across a question in my mind do microkernels also have per process stack like Linux has?

Comment: Yes, by definition.  Every thread must have its own stack.

Comment: It is clear to me that every process needs a stack to pass arguments and allocate local variables what I mean is, does every process in microkernel also has stack in kernel space, like every process in linux has kernel stack?

Comment: No..............